# How to accept two authentication schemes in IdentityServer4?

Tags: oauth-2.0, session-cookies, identityserver4, openid-connect, bearer-token

Currently my app is accepting Cookies ("idsrv.session") to authenticate the user, however when i try to add the "bearer" token in the hearder of a request it just says unauthorized.
However if i change the configuration of the IdServer but adding ".AddJwtBearer" it accepts now a request with an header containing the "bearer" token but no longer accepts requests containing cookies.

Is it possible to implement both approaches, to accept cookies or in case no cookie is received, to check if the header contains a "bearer" token?

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: Many thanks @leastprivilege